# Is it a single thread to listen for service fabric remoting endpoint

Tags: multithreading, azure-service-fabric, remoting

For one remoting endpoint in service fabric microservice, is there only one thread listening for it? thanks.

Comment: Well, you can find it out rather easily: create a service with a method that sleeps for 10 seconds and call it twice. Will the second call only be performed after 10 seconds (hint: the answer is no)

Answer (score 0):

If you literally mean "listening", like listen for incoming connections, like server socket that opens a port on the network and then wait for a client to connect to that port, then yes. But if you mean threads that eventually process requests, then there will be several of them. In fact, you could even control this part -

1. **FabricTransportServiceRemotingListener** accepts **FabricTransportRemotingListenerSettings** with the property called **MaxConcurrentCalls**.
2. With **WcfServiceRemotingListener**, it depends on binding. Like with NetTcpBinding , which is a default one if you don't specify binding explicitly, you get **MaxConnections** property. **It's not the same though** - it's more about controlling how many connections will be queued before getting rejected. Potentially, you could consider implementing your own IServiceRemotingMessageHandler which WcfServiceRemotingListener accepts in one of its constructors, and place there your own throttling logic.